# Is there a way to change color of just part of a string inside a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Say I wanted to have the first six characters in black and the next six characters in blue, then the last 20 characters in black of a `UILabel`. Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Darren said, NSAttributedString is not supported on the iPhone but you could use a UIWebView.

Another possible solution might be to draw the text using NSString's `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` method (or similar). You could subclass UILabel and do the drawing in `-drawRect:`.

First, set the color to black and draw the first six characters. Note the width that `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` returns, and use it to calculate the starting point for the next six characters. Change the color, draw those characters, and then repeat the same for the remainder of the string.

Note that `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` doesn't do line breaks and stuff like that, so it could quickly get more complicated than what I've described.

Have a look at the [NSString UIKit additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 3):

In Big Cocoa you would use an NSAttributedString in a NSTextField or NSTextView.  In Cocoa Touch you use a UIWebView to display rich text.

Answer (score 1):

Zynga has done a lot of the heavy lifting for you on this one, check out [Font Label](http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks! I only need a few uses of multicolored text, but that's a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

Give [TTTAttributedString](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) a try. It's a drop-in replacement for UILabel that renders NSAttributedStrings like a champ.

Answer (score -3):

You want an NSAttributedString.

Comment: NSAttributedString is not supported in Cocoa Touch (on the iPhone).